# xslt generating element of current position and value of next in nested nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Considering given code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$data/row">
    <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1" >
        <xsl:element name="{current()}" >
            <xsl:value-of select="/*next element somehow*/" />
        </xsl:element>  
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

How can I get value of next element, when I know that this is even element in my foreach loop?

Answer (score 2):

Do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::row[1]" />
```

Do note, this actually gets the first `row` element that follows the current row, but it need not be immediately adjacent. For example, if your XML looked like this...

```
<data>
   <row>1</row>
   <extrarow>1</extrarow>
   <row>2</row>
</data>
```

Then, if you were on row 1, and did the above statement, it would get row 2. If you wanted to get `extrarow` (or whatever element immediately following the current one), do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]" />
```

Note that you can combine the `xsl:for-each` and `xsl:if` into one, like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$data/row[position() mod 2 = 1]" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use positional grouping instead:

```
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$data/row" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 2">
          <xsl:element name="{.}">
              <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[2]"/>
          </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
```

Example: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rNu